# How to create and read text files in Java

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse for a university project making an android app.
I'm having a problem with 1 thing:

I have created a class called `TextFileHandler`. 
The idea is that the app instantiates `TextFileHandler` and uses the methods 
to read and write the text files within the app with get methods simply 
returning a string value and set methods writing new values to the text files.

When this class is instantiated the constructor creates a text file. 
The methods are supposed to access the created text files and read and write them 
but the problem is, once it creates the text files it can't seem to access them 
and the app just crashes.

I have included the constructor and then directly after the method `getMeds()`
which just crashes every time. I'm not sure why it can't find the text files.

Any help would be appreciated.

**constructor:**

```
public TextFileHandler(Context ctx){
    this.context = ctx;
    //create the medicine text file
    String medtext = "1#Med*2#Med*3#Med*4#Med*5#Med*";
    try {
          File file = new File("Medicine.txt");
          //if the file doesn't already exist then create it
          //this is to make sure the app saves state
          if(!file.exists()){
              BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
              output.write(medtext);
              output.close();                     
          }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }


    String remtext = "1a#000000*1b#000000*1c#000000*1d#000000*1e#000000*";
    remtext += "2a#000000*2b#000000*2c#000000*2d#000000*2e#000000*";
    remtext += "3a#000000*3b#000000*3c#000000*3d#000000*3e#000000*";
    remtext += "4a#000000*4b#000000*4c#000000*4d#000000*4e#000000*";
    remtext += "5a#000000*5b#000000*5c#000000*5d#000000*5e#000000*";
    try {
          File file = new File("Reminder.txt");
          //if the file doesn't already exist then create it
          //this is to make sure the app saves state
          if(!file.exists()){
              BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
              output.write(remtext);
              output.close();                     
          }
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
           e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

**get method:**

```
public String getMeds() throws IOException{
    FileInputStream in = openFileInput("Medicine.txt");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(in);
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line);
    }
    String ret = sb.toString();
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: 1) Please edit your question to include the *full* text of the error you are getting when your application crashes. 2) Have you verified that the file is, in fact, created when your application starts?

Answer (score 0):

Create your file either privately (readable only by your app) using `ctx.openFileOutput("Medicine.txt", MODE_PRIVATE)` or publicly using `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Medicine.txt")`.

To read the private file, use `Context.openFileInput(String name)`.